# Sql Server: How can one find all the DML triggers that are registered for DELETE (among other actions, possibly)?

Tags: sql-server

I can list all the triggers with their code, but I do not understand how to see which ones are invoked on DELETE, except by parsing the trigger code - would like to avoid that very much.

Is there a way in Sql Server to figure out if a trigger is a delete trigger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it. According to the page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/objectproperty-transact-sql we can use the `ExecIsDeleteTrigger` property of a trigger.

So, the following query returns all the DML DELETE triggers with the trigger sql code conveniently arranged as a clickable hyper link:

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(parent_id) TableName,Name TriggerName,CAST('<![CDATA[' + OBJECT_DEFINITION(object_id) + ']]>' AS XML) SqlCode
FROM sys.triggers
WHERE parent_class = 1 AND OBJECTPROPERTY(object_id, 'ExecIsDeleteTrigger') = 1
ORDER BY TableName
```

Comment: Nice find.  There are a lot of ways to parse through scripts, hence my answer, but this way is certainly better.